# How would I limit speed of dc motor being used as a generator?

Tags: dc, dc-motor, generator

How would I limit speed of a DC motor being used as a generator?
For a project where I have to make a wind turbine that will automatically limit speed of rotation once past a certain value.
Thanks :)

Comment: (1) By feathering the blades. (2) By turning it out of the wind. (3) By increasing the electrical load. What have you condsidered?

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

1. Rotate the motor so the blades are out of the wind
2. Change the pitch of the blades by rotating them at the base, so they are no longer effective, if they can have that capability. Also called 'feathering'.
3. Use a mechanical brake (you could use a mechanical clutch but that would allow the blades to turn faster, which could cause [problems](https://youtu.be/7nSB1SdVHqQ)).
4. Apply additional load to the motor, dumping heat into a dummy load if necessary

Comment: Your 2 is pitch control...